# Can we update docker image

Tags: python, docker, build, addition, dockerhub

So i use docker to build image with command `docker build` 
so the image may follows this example :

```
RUN mkdir /somefolder/someapp
ADD mycode /somefolder/someapp
WORKDIR "/somefolder"
```

So as you can see , i need to add the folder **mycode** which contain all of my python code to the work directory. And it works all fine to the deployment.

Now i need to change some code file in **mycode** folder. Is there anyway i can automatically update the image , not rebuilding it again using `docker build`

Comment: No, that's not how docker works. If you want to do that, you might need to consider mounting volumes.

Comment: so is there anyway else because i dont realy want to rebuild the entire image whenever i alter my source code.

Comment: You should mounting volumes, because using ADD in this way is not how docker works.

Comment: Images are immutable, once created they don't change. You replace them with new images. (And volumes are the correct answer for your development workflow.)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to rebuild the image or not using mount point, which is not recommended. Then you can change the container files by following this steps
http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/

If you think rebuilding entire image takes much time its false, because only changes that u made in dockerfile will be commit reset will be taken from the pre-build images ( intermediate image layers ).

Comment: Rebuilding a docker image can indeed take much time - if he has slow stuff after his ADD command. Everything from your first change gets rebuilt - not just changed commands.